# Bringing back the Rileys

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Not seen a Riley in a while so I've decided to bring them back.

**RULES**

> I will give a riddle/clue for 3 different words.
>
> Each of the clues will be the prefix, infix, or suffix, of a word.
>
> Combining the three words (sometimes including letter overlaps), will form another word.
>
> Your task is to find each of the words referenced by the clues, and then the final formed word.
>
> I've decided to make this a bit trickier by not telling you the order of words in the final combination.

**RIDDLE**

> I'm an action that uses an eye that cannot see.
>
> Becoming one of these is a big ask.
>
> You might dance to me whilst inside of me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you a

> HOUSEWIFE?

I'm an action that uses an eye that cannot see.

> As per mrdeadsven, this is SEW.

Becoming one of these is a big ask.

> To become a WIFE, the big question to pop is “Will You Marry Me?”

You might dance to me whilst inside of me.

> You could dance to HOUSE music whilst inside a HOUSE.

Comment: Ding Ding Ding Mr Elite gets it once again

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer

I'm an action that uses an eye that cannot see.

> I would say a needle (it has an eye and can't see) and the action you do is SEW.

Comment: Good thinking ;)

Comment: @AHKieran thanks, still thinking for the rest of the riddle but so far I really like the concept of it :)